# How do I programmatically read the value of an attached dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

So I have a Button with an AutomationId (used by Microsoft UI Automation) like so:

```
<Button Name="myButton" AutomationId="myButtonAutomationID"
```

Programmatically, I have the button (myButton) in code, how do I get the value of the 'AutomationId' property attached to that button?

Comment: [Check this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationidproperty.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`DependencyObject.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue.aspx) should do the job:

```
string automationId = 
    (string)myButton.GetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty);
```

Comment: Can avoid the cast and improve code readability by simply calling `AutomationProperties.GetAutomationId(myButton)`

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, just as you would with any other `DependencyProperty`; the ordinary properties on your object serve (or *should* serve) as simple wrappers around `DependencyObject.GetValue` and `.SetValue`, so all you need to do is call `GetValue` yourself and pass in your `static readonly` instance of your attached `DependencyProperty`:

```
var value = myButton.GetValue(yourDependencyProperty);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var automationId = AutomationProperties.GetAutomationId(myButton);
```

As is standard for dependency properties, this wrapper method will do the job of calling `DependencyObject.GetValue` for you, and casting the value to the correct type.